# Deployed Web application getting nosuchmethod error for javax.json.JsonValue.asJsonArray - Jboss eap 7.0 linux server

Tags: jboss-eap-7, javax.json

I have a web application deployed to jboss eap 7.0 on linux.

Within my java code I am using `javax.json.JsonValue.asJsonArray` method. 
 When I run locally on tomcat all runs fine.

Once I deploy to Jboss I get a nosuchmethod error on asJsonArray method.  within my WEB-INF\lib folder I have the necessary json jar with that method `javax.json-1.1.4.jar`. I have discovered that under modules within Jboss it has its own version of `javax.json` `\jboss-eap-7.0\modules\system\layers\base\org\glassfish\javax\json\main\javax.json-1.0.3.redhat-1.jar`.

It is my speculation that when I run my application it is first looking at jar within the Jboss modules directory rather than the jar within the `WEB-INF\lib` folder in the war file. How do I direct the application to reference the jar within the `WEB-INF\lib` and not the jar withing the jboss modules?

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude the JBoss provided dependency using jboss-deployment-structure.xml file which you need to place under the WEB-INF directory of your war. You have to specify the exclusion dependencies something like below.

```
`<jboss-deployment-structure>  
 <deployment>  
    <exclusions>  
        <module name="$LIBRARY_OR_MODULE_YOU_WANT_TO_EXCLUDE"/>  
    </exclusions>  
 </deployment>
 </jboss-deployment-structure>`
```

e.g. `<module name="javax.json.api"/>`